# ansible hcloud set_fact add items from list in dict

Tags: ansible, yaml

I am trying myself on the ansible hcloud modules.
I need to set a fact list with the IPs of the server that I create.

The first server is easy, as it is always just one:

Create empty list:

```
    - set_fact:
        ips: []
```

Then create the server and add the server IP to the list:

```
    - set_fact:
        ips:
          - "{{ ips + [ a3srv_fact.hcloud_server.ipv4_address ] }}"
```

Next block is with a loop, therefore the register gives me this:

```
"hc_fact": {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "All items completed",
    "results": [
        {
            "ansible_loop_var": "item",
            "changed": false,
            "failed": false,
            "hcloud_server": {
                "backup_window": "None",
                "datacenter": "nbg1-dc3",
                "id": "3083849",
                "image": "centos-7",
                "ipv4_address": "116.203.204.49",
                "ipv6": "2a01:4f8:c2c:ade4::/64",
                "labels": {},
                "location": "nbg1",
                "name": "a3hc1",
                "rescue_enabled": false,
                "server_type": "cx11",
                "status": "running"
            },
            "invocation": {
                "module_args": {
                    "api_token": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER",
                    "backups": false,
                    "datacenter": null,
                    "endpoint": "https://api.hetzner.cloud/v1",
                    "force_upgrade": false,
                    "id": null,
                    "image": "centos-7",
                    "labels": null,
                    "location": null,
                    "name": "a3hc1",
                    "server_type": "cx11",
                    "ssh_keys": null,
                    "state": "present",
                    "upgrade_disk": false,
                    "user_data": null,
                    "volumes": null
                }
            },
            "item": "hc1"
        },
        {
            "ansible_loop_var": "item",
            "changed": false,
            "failed": false,
            "hcloud_server": {
                "backup_window": "None",
                "datacenter": "nbg1-dc3",
                "id": "3083921",
                "image": "centos-7",
                "ipv4_address": "116.203.204.136",
                "ipv6": "2a01:4f8:c2c:ae25::/64",
                "labels": {},
                "location": "nbg1",
                "name": "a3hc2",
                "rescue_enabled": false,
                "server_type": "cx11",
                "status": "running"
            },
            "invocation": {
                "module_args": {
                    "api_token": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER",
                    "backups": false,
                    "datacenter": null,
                    "endpoint": "https://api.hetzner.cloud/v1",
                    "force_upgrade": false,
                    "id": null,
                    "image": "centos-7",
                    "labels": null,
                    "location": null,
                    "name": "a3hc2",
                    "server_type": "cx11",
                    "ssh_keys": null,
                    "state": "present",
                    "upgrade_disk": false,
                    "user_data": null,
                    "volumes": null
                }
            },
            "item": "hc2"
        }
    ]
}
```

The result block can have 1 or more parts, there are two.

I need to add every ipv4_address to a existing fact list.

I am pretty sure there is a straightforward way with yml syntax, but I just cant get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use json_query. The task below

```
- set_fact:
    ips: "{{ ips|default([]) +
             hc_fact.results|
             json_query('[*].hcloud_server.ipv4_address')
             }}"
```

gives

```
"ips": [
    "116.203.204.49", 
    "116.203.204.136"
]
```